# Why do these types of inverters produce different output power?

Tags: inverter, induction

In induction heating we generaly use single-switch, half-bridge and full-bridge inverters to generate power. Why is it that they can't all produce the same average power?

Single-switch:[image: Single-switch]
Half-bridge:

Full-bridge:[image: Half-bridge]

[image: Full-bridge]

Comment: They can, if you scale them right.

Comment: Ok. So it's gonna be harder for me to explain why this is. In induction heating generally half-bridge is used for 5 kW and up, half-bridge from 2 kW up and single-switch below that. Any tip on why this is so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the peak-peak output voltage you get for a given supply voltage for each arrangement.

Comment: Full-bridge and single-switch get full source voltage and half-bridge gets only half of source voltage across the load. But that doesn't explain why single-switch is only used for lowest power levels.

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your links, so this is an educated guess...

Both bridge configurations are using semiconductor devices, and can switch a heater on and off reliably for years.

A single-switch configuration, using something like a relay or contactor to interrupt power to the heater is going to fail due to contact arcing, especially at higher power levels.  Mercury relays were often used in this configuration, as they did not have the contact breakdown problem, but due to the toxicity of mercury, and difficulty of disposing, they have mostly been phased out, to be replaced with semiconductor devices.

Comment: Ok, all these configurations are using IGBT (transistors) at over 20 kHz. There is no other difference between them so contact arcing isn't the issue.